General form of the Faraday tensor
When deriving the Faraday tensor we use the fact that the two potentials with the Lorentz gauge $U$ and $\vec{A}$ can be written as one 4-vector potential $\vec{A}_4 \equiv (U/c\ ,\vec{A})$ and the connection between the E&M field and the potentials:
$$\vec{E}=-\vec{\nabla}U-\partial_t\vec{A} \\ 
  \vec{B}=\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{A}$$
Now I want to derive the Faraday tensor without assuming orthonormal or constant basis so that the derivation can be as general as possible so when we expand theose two equations we get:
$$\frac{1}{c}E^i=-\nabla_iA_4^0-\nabla_iA_4^i \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \\
B^i=\mathcal{E}^{jki}\nabla_jA_{4\ k} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ i,j,k\geq 1$$
Here $\mathcal{E}^{jki}=\varepsilon^{jki}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\text{det}(g)}}$ and $\nabla_i$ is the covariant derivative. Now what all the sources I managed to find do is to assume we work in an orthonormal basis so ($\nabla_i=\partial_i$ ) and they ignore the cronecker delta symbol in the sense of its properties of being a relative pseudotensor and not just a regular tensor. So they get the convinient form of $\hat{F}$:
$$F^{ij}=\partial^iA_4^j-\partial^jA_4^i$$
And just call it a tensor. However I'm not sure this thing will work out of the scope of orthonormal (in Lorentzian sense) noncurvilinear coordinate systems. The most obvious thing is that if we just postulate $\hat{F}$ transforms always as a tensor it would ignore the relativity of $\hat{\mathcal{E}}$. Am I wrong? Am I missing something? If assuming rectilinear coordinate systems doesn't lose generality, how so?

Can you clarify what you mean by deriving the Faraday tensor? Assuming that you don't want to go all the way to differential forms (in which $\mathcal F = \mathrm d \mathcal A$ in any coordinates you like), are you just asking for an expression for the components of $F$ in terms of derivatives of the components of $A$?

I think my question is this: We define $F^{ij}$ the way I wrote it in my post, ok no derivation needed for definition. However then the textbooks say this equals a tensor filled with $\vec{E}/c$ and $\vec{B}$ components and it seems to me that those two things would be equal only in orthonormal rectilinear coordinates since we ignored the relative pseudotensor which pops up in the magnetic field components.

It turns out that $F_{\mu\nu}=\partial_\mu A_\nu -\partial_\nu A_\mu= \nabla_\mu A_\nu -\nabla_\nu A_\mu$ so it works in any coordinate system.

What do you mean by "a tensor filled with $\vec{E}/c$ and $\vec{B}$"?
It seems that you may be referring to a matrix, which is a representation under a specific local coordinate system on your space-time manifold, the components of the matrix will generally change under a change of basis but the definition
$F=dA$ where $A\in\Omega^{1}(U)$ is always true, regardless of the coordinate system and is invariant under change of basis.
you can quite easily check this with a general $A= A_{\mu}dx^{\mu}~~\mu\in\lbrace 0,1,2,3\rbrace$ (summation convention is in use) and apply the exterior derivative to it and then a change of basis.
Note that the sign convention of the metric is irrelevant, you will either get $F^{0i}\propto E^i$ or $F^{0i}\propto -E^i$.
